# What to do about missing jummuah for class?

Tags: jumuah, school

I have a mandatory math session for my college class that I must attend or I fail and it starts the same time as jummuah which is also mandatory for me to attend what should I do in this case?

I would choose jummuah any day but I don't want to have to repeat this class?

Comment: Did you discuss it with your teacher, they should be understanding, if not then speak to someone at a higher position, do explain that this is a religious obligation!

Answer (score 3):

If you have any other Muslim brothers (more than two, excluding you) who attend the maths session with you, you can group together after the session finishes and perform the Jumu'a prayer together, as long as Asr time didn't come.

The Khutba isn't necessary to be complex, it can just be simply an interpretation of a hadeeth, discussing the meanings in an aya etc.

If you don't have any Muslim colleagues, then try to negotiate with the teacher about the timing of the session. As jumu'a prayer has to be done no matter what. The Prophet Muhammad PBUH said:

> مَنْ ترك ثَلاثَ جمعاتٍ ، مِنْ غيرِ عذرٍ ، كُتِبَ مِنَ المنافقينَ.
>   الراوي : أسامة بن زيد | المحدث : الألباني | المصدر : صحيح الجامع
>   الصفحة أو الرقم: 6144 | خلاصة حكم المحدث : صحيح

Which means that whoever leaves three Friday prayers, is written to be from the hypocrites.

And Allah knows best.